# Get Alert on low disk space

Tags: hardware, email, disk-space

Is it on MacOS possible to get notified by eMail if the space on a disk gets low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script that will do what you need.  Let me know if you need a hand configuring it (although the article goes into detail about configuring it to check at intervals etc)

http://www.macmanager.com.au/software/low_space_script.html